# How can I hide a DatePicker icon when its DateTextField is hidden?

Tags: java, wicket

I'm using a `DatePicker` (`org.apache.wicket.extensions.yui.calendar.DatePicker` — [Javadoc](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/extensions/yui/calendar/DatePicker.html)) in a form. The form consists of two fields. The first field is a dropdown, and the second changes dynamically based on the first. If "text" is selected, a textbox comes up; if "list" is selected, a dropdown menu comes up; and if "date" is selected, a date picker and associated field come up.

Here's a simplified version of my current code:

```
DateTextField dateField = new DateTextField("dateField", // ...
DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
dateField.add(datePicker);

fieldOne.add(new OnChangeAjaxBehavior() {
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        if (fieldOne.equalsIgnoreCase("list"))
        {
            dateField.setVisible(false);
            // datePicker.setVisible(false); // This line is impossible
            listField.setVisible(true);
            textField.setVisible(false);
        }
        else if { /* similar visibility settings for dates and text */ }
    }
});
```

The form currently works properly for changing *to* the date picker. The problem arises when date is selected and then the user selects something else. The date *field* disappears, but the date *picker* remains on the screen. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have a `setVisible()` method, or any equivalent. In fact, it's not even a true Wicket `Component`.

How can I make them appear/disappear together? If I can't set the picker's visibility directly, can I tie it to the field's visibility somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the easiest yet still fairly maintainable solution is to group the components you want to hide together in a `WebMarkupContainer`. In the markup you'll probably want to use a `<div>` element for the container, but this depends on what you want to hide. (Sometimes the markup itself prevents you from using this method but let's hope your markup doesn't. :))

Then just change the visibility of the container.

Comment: I have attempted to do this (and I'm continuing to play with it) but I can't actually get the picker inside the `WebMarkupContainer`. The picker is only present in the generated HTML, not the source I write. So, when I try to wrap it all in the container, what happens is that neither the field nor the picker ever appear.

Comment: Ah, I finally got this working. Turns out I missed one of the `setVisible()` calls I needed.

Comment: I don't know if it's good or bad practice, but what I often do is override `isVisible()` instead. It makes it really easy to scan a component and find out how the show/hide logic works.

Answer (score 0):

A good idea with AjaxListeners also is to call `.setOutputMarkupId(true)` on the Component you want to handle. Otherwise you are possibly not able to "locate" it.

In case you are not rendering it on load, but intend to add the component later, I think you should also call `setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true)`.

This helped me several times...